# Convert Multiple User Inputs that are integers into string

Tags: java, string, int, converters

I created a scanner class and I want to convert the user inputs that are integers into a string that prints them out like num1:num2:num3

```
int num1 = scan.nextInt();
int num2 = scan.nextInt();
int num3 = scan.nextInt();
```

I want to be able to make it so I can use the string in

```
System.out.println();
```

without having to do num1 + ":" num2 + ":" + num3 every time i want to use the string.

Comment: Do you know how many int's you are expecting?  Just put the scan in a loop and the prints in a loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can introduce a local variable:

```
String myString = num1 + ":" num2 + ":" + num3;
```

Then you can use it directly:

```
System.out.println(myString);
```

Also, this could be a more convenient way:

```
String myString = String.format("%d:%d:%d", num1, num2, num3);
```

[`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) enables you to specify a format string (`"%d:%d:%d"` this time), so if you happen to want to change it later on, you can do it easily.

As @Pshemo noted, similar to how String.format works, there is the [`PrintStream.printf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method, available in this scenario as `System.out.printf(String format, Object... args)`:

```
System.out.printf("%d:%d:%d", num1, num2, num3);
```

*Another aspect to consider:* would you happen to experience a change in the requirements (e.g.: not 3, but more, or even arbitrary number of input), you should consider using arrays (or anz of the appropriate Collections: List or Set implementations) for storing the inputs, and writing a function to provide the desired string out of that.

In that case, the **Apache Commons [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)** can come in handy: it has a nice polymorphic join method, offering to join just anbout anything:

```
//given an int[] named myArray:
String myString = StringUtils.join(myArray, ':');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(num1);
sb.append(":");
sb.append(num2);
sb.append(":");
sb.append(num3);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

As the `append` methods return a reference to the *same* object, these calls can be chained:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(num1).append(":").append(num2).append(":").append(num3);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Varieties of overloaded `append` methods give you power to append several other types to the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: this is similar to `String s = num1 + ":" + num2 + ":" + num3`.

Comment: They have similar effects but they aren't actually the same. The time taken to concatenate n strings using the string concatenation operator is quadratic in n.

Comment: The java compiler translates the simple concatenation `num1 + ":" + num2 + ":" + num3` to a `StringBuilder.append` sequence. So I see nothing different. Indeed, if you want to do it in a loop is better to use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Get the string like you did before and store it inside a string:

```
String numbers = num1 + ":" + num2 + ":" + num3;
```

Then print it:

```
System.out.println(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Guava [Guava from Google](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) is something that could help you. Among other stuff it has this nice utility classes.

```
public void concatenate() {
    // Your user input, which could be maybe optimised as well
    int int1 = 10;
    int int2 = 20;
    int int3 = 30;
    int int4 = 40;

    System.out.println(
         Joiner.on(":") // delimiter that will be used
            .join(ImmutableSet.of(int1, int2, int3, int4)));  // Guava which creates temp list for you
}
```

Result:

```
10:20:30:40
```

Comment: Using another library only to concatenate strings seems overkill to me.